# iOS - UITableViewCell subclass with two different images

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, subclass

I'm subclassing UITableViewCell to have one image on the far left, then some text in the middle and then some text on the far right.

This UITableViewCell subclass will only have two images depending on a condition. What I've done before when I have used images in UITableViewCell subclass I have declared them as

```
static UIImage *image = nil;
```

and then in the `+(void)initialize` method I have assigned them. This is made only to have a class instances of the images and not using up resources to assign these images to every instance of UITableViewCell.

So my question is now, depending on a condition in my UIViewController that is calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I should show a UITableViewCell with imageA or imageB. So in pseudo-code it would look something like this

```
if (conditionA) { 
    // Set image of cell to be imageA 
} else { 
    // Set image of cell to be imageB 
}
```

So how do I achieve this with a subclassed UITableViewCell? I was thinking of one way would be to observe a property in the UITableViewCell and when that property would change I would set the cell image accordingly but that seems to be a little bloated for something that should be pretty easy?

The ideal way would be to set it in the init method of the UITableViewCell but then I would not be able to reuse the cells right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about redundant images being created for each instance. The `UIImage` class already has an inbuilt cache, and it does not create a new image instances as long as you are creating them using the `imageNamed:` selector.

From the docs for the `imageNamed:` method in `UIImage`,

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.

If the two images are predefined and won't change, then you can simplify the subclasses cell's interface. Only allow the users of this subclass to tell it which type of image should be used. You could use an `enum` for that.

In the UITableViewCell's subclass header, create the enum. Use whatever names suits your use-case.

```
typedef enum {
  ImageTypeOne,
  ImageTypeTwo
} ImageType;

@property (nonatomic) ImageType imageType;
```

Inside the implementation, override the generated setter as:

```
- (void)setImageType:(ImageType)newImageType {
    imageType = newImageType;

    if (imageType == ImageTypeOne) {
        theImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one"];
    } 
    else if (imageType == ImageTypeOne) {
        theImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"two"];
    }
    // this will resize the image view to fit the image.
    [theImageView sizeToFit];
}
```

Inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, simply set this property depending on the condition.

```
if (conditionA) { 
    myCustomCell.imageType = ImageTypeOne;
} else { 
    myCustomCell.imageType = ImageTypeTwo;
}
```

Comment: Aha thanks for straightening that out. These images are different sizes. Where do I set the frame for these images? In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or in the `UITableViewCell` subclass (where specifically and how?, if so)

Comment: If the two images are predefined and won't change, you could use an enum to set which image must be shown, and expose that as a property on the cell subclass. Override the default setter for the imageView and call `sizeToFit:` to resize. It'll take care of the frame. Let me update the answer.

Comment: The images are set in the upperleft corner of the UITableViewCell. I would need to reposition them. Do I do that after I call `sizeToFit` in the setter or do I reposition in `layoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 0):

> The ideal way would be to set it in the init method of the
>   UITableViewCell but then I would not be able to reuse the cells right?

That's correct, but there's solution not too far away. Use the same technique with two static images and update the `imageView`'s image with a special method like `updateMyCellImage` depending on the key property value.

The second step is to prepare such a setter for that key property, that would call this method after the value of the key property is changed.

Then you'll only need to set the key property value at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after the cell is dequeued/initialized and the `imageView`'s image will be updated for you, you'll be able to reuse the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the use of the `static UIImage`. The view should not own it's data.

If this was me I would have a property for each `UIImage` in the dataSource that was only instantiated once and then I would just configure the cells normally by having the dataSource tell them what to display.

It seems like your making more work for yourself and introducing a very rigid structure

Comment: I could do it that way as well. But the images have different sizes so I would need to set the frame of the cell.imageView depending on what image is displayed in the cell. How would I deal with that?

Comment: Well you could either have the controller set it, or you could set the frames in `layoutSubviews`